# Get area surface and ceiling height with RoomPlan

Tags: ios, swift, surface, roomplan

Can't see it it the doc but, do you know/think it's possible to get the surface of a room in square meter and the ceiling heigh in meter ? Thanks

Comment: Ok so I finished by crawling all the walls to get the max height and suppose it's the ceiling height. But I can't figure how to get the floor surface in square meter. It seems that we can get the whole result box surface but it will definitely be bigger because it will be a rectangle and the scanned room is not necessarily...

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no direct way to get a room surface area. You have to calculate it by your own considering surfaces you got from scanning.
Apple announced a new surface category which is floor in iOS 17. Maybe it might simplify surface area calculations

Answer (score -2):

```
let length = 4.0 // Length of the room in meters
let width = 5.0 // Width of the room in meters
let height = 2.5 // Height of the room in meters

let surfaceArea = length * width * height 
let ceilingHeight = height

print("The surface area of the room is \(surfaceArea) square meters.")
print("The height of the ceiling is \(ceilingHeight) meters.")
```

Comment: Well, thank you, I already have the formula :) But where can I get these values from RoomPlan CapturedRoom object... It seems that ceiling is not supported :/ As a reminder, RoomPlan only have 4 types of surface : Walls, Doors, Windows and Opening. And I want to get the whole room surface